# Outlook VSTO addin messing with the reply action in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Installing the outlook VSTO addin I developed cause a weird phenomenon in outlook (2013 & 2016). The addin is Form region type (Adjoining) with message class - Note.

**The phenomenon:**
When user in trying to reply an email the email is opened in edit mode but without separator line and free space for reply:

[Reply - No separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVVrz.png)

While I expect to get it with a separator:

[Reply - With separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Jki.png)

Unistalling the addin fix the reply problem. Any ideas what can cause it?

Comment: What does your addin do when a new message is created?

Comment: Does using a Task Panel instead of a form region produce the same result?

Comment: The addin does nothing relevant to the mail body when a new message is created, just few things relevant for setting the form width and select default tab (from tab controller). as for the Task Panel, I cannot test it because I can't reproduce the problem in my PC (I have 2016, and still...)